# Picture in Picture camera swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera, picture-in-picture

I'm trying to get the Picture in Picture working for my camera view on my iPad.
I see on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_for_video_calls) that we can do it more easily on iOS 16 for video calls.

The result I'm trying to get is to be able to see the camera of the user in PiP while being in the background.

One way of doing that is to fake a video call (like Zoom, Messenger, etc) but that seems overkill. I am able to view my video using `UIImagePickerController` but I'm wondering if there is an easy way to integrate it in PiP?

Comment: I am trying to implement the same for iphone, is it possible to do so?